# Package as DMG Image in NetBeans 9 & 11, JDK 11 returns "typedef class com.sun.javafx.tools.ant.FXJar cannot be found using the.."

Tags: java, netbeans, ant

I am trying to package a Java project as native installers in NetBeans and am getting the following error in the output: "typedef class com.sun.javafx.tools.ant.FXJar cannot be found
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[]".  The line of code referred to is in build-native.xml and reads: "".

I've tried both "All installers" and "DMG Image" in the "Package as" submenu, in both NetBeans 9 and 11, both with JDK 11.0.1+13.  I have read around the topic to try to understand what is going wrong and how to fix it, but can't find anything directly relevant.  I've tried re-assembling the project class by class, and also tried a simple "Hello World", but am getting the same error in all cases.  My project does not use any JavaFX, so I question why it should need ...javafx.tools...

I would expect to get a JAR file and 'lib' folder in the 'dist' folder, and DMG (+ EXE etc) packages somewhere within the project folder, but am only getting the 'lib' folder with JAR for a library that's on the classpath.

I'm pretty clueless when it comes to JDK & IDE setup, as well as native packaging, so please try to make answers as idiot-proof as possible!

Comment: The missing line of code in the first paragraph is "<typedef name="fx_jar" classname="com.sun.javafx.tools.ant.FXJar" classpath="${javafx.ant.classpath}"/>".  Not sure how that got missed.

Comment: Just to be clear, I have used the 'clean and build' function which put a working JAR in the dist folder as expected, but on running the 'package as' options I'm still getting the same errors and no native packages.

Answer (score 0):

Tried everything.  I am giving up on NetbBeans native packaging for now.  Hopefully by the next time I update my app it will work.

For now I have a very crude solution that may work for others:  Create the new .app package by modifying an old version of the app made with JDK 8.  Here are the steps.

Steps to create a new mac app from an old mac app package:

1. Right click/control click existing .app package.
2. Click 'Show Package Contents'.
3. Double click 'Contents' in the finder window that opens.
4. Double click 'Java'.
5. Remove the existing JAR from this folder, and add the new JAR of your project.
6. Rename the new JAR with the exact same name as the old JAR you removed.  If this does not match your project it does not matter - the user will not see it.
7. If the old project had dependancies, I'm guessing there will be a lib folder in the Java folder.  You may want to remove this, and/or add a lib folder for your new project if the dependancies are different between the two projects.
8. Double click 'Plugins' and double click Java.runtime.
9. Replace the 'Contents' folder with the folder with the same name from your JDK installation.  Mine is in [ssd]/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk .
10. Replace the icon in the 'Resources' folder with a different one if desired.
11. Codesign and notarize the app if necessary.  The old codesignature will be broken as the app contents have changed.  I will leave working out how to do this for another day or another person.

Now I have to figure out if I can do the same for Windows and Linux packages.

Answer (score 0):

For NetBeans native packaging to work the NetBeans application must itself be run using a JDK8 platform in order to pick up the correct JavaFX components.

Running NetBeans in the following way on Mac OSX and Native Pacaging works:

1. Open terminal
2. Go  "/Applications/NetBeans/Apache NetBeans 11.3.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/netbeans/bin/netbeans" --jdkhome /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_221.jdk/Contents/Home

ensuring that jdkhome points to a valid jdk1.8.  This is essential.

Comment: As JDK 14 is now officially out, I would try the new jpackage tool, which is coming with it, instead of getting some outdated JDK to work.